# Android 8 Oreo - No more "pause feedback" for Talkback in accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

I am developing apps for Android and now have started to use Android 8 (Oreo) on my Pixel 2-phone.

While working on the accessibility of an app I've noticed that a certain entry in the "Global Context Menu" is missing when you use the gesture to open the menu (Swipe down -> then right while Talkback is enabled).

Namely the entry "pause feedback" is gone, which ... well ... paused the Talkback-reader, so you could click normally around in your app. The entry is still mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6007066?hl=en) by Google.

This makes it somewhat harder to work on accessibility for an app, since you need either to click around a lot more or constantly enable / disable the Talkback-reader.

Is there another way to pause the Talkback-reader temporarily or to get the "pause feedback" entry back?

[image: Pause feedback missing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suspend TalkBack by pressing both volume buttons for a couple of seconds. You can un-suspend it by doing the same thing.

Comment: This definitively helps, but a "software-based" solution would be a bit nicer I feel. This way I have to lift the phone up and sometimes I turn up the volume by accident. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I used to do that at first but with some practice you don't turn up the volume any more.

Comment: I am working in a company so we have several (around 30?) different smartphones. Most of them are not Android 8, but soon we will get another batch of different Android 8 phones, so this will take a while until I hit every key on every phone correctly... a genereic gestures therefore would be preferable, but the volume key has to do for now.

Comment: I'm in a similar position (QA) with lots of smarphones to test on. I haven't found a better way to quickly turn on or off TalckBack.

Comment: It's far less convenient. Can't understand why they changed this. Using this function all the time helping my blind relatives with their phones. I can only say that setting up a phone for a blind person is painful and things do not work as reliably as one would hope :/